# Prove or give counter example: If $f(x)$ is concave and nonincreasing, $g(x)$ is convex, then $f(g(x))$ is convex

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I can solve similar cases, like:

> "If $f(x)$ is convex, $g(x)$ is convex, then $f(g(x))$ is convex",

but I am not sure how to solve when $f(x)$ is concave non-increasing. Mainly I want to know where and how to use the given information of $f(x)$ being non-increasing.

Answer (score 0):

If both functions are derivable twice on a certain open interval where the conditions are fulfilled, then you get (I'm traducing "concave"=concave downwards, like say $\;-x^2\;$ ,  "convex"=concave upwards, say $\;x^2\;$)

$$\left(f(g(x)\right)''=\left(f'(g(x))g'(x)\right)'=f''(g(x))g'(x)^2+f'(g(x))g''(x)<0$$

which means $\;f(g(x))\;$ is concave downwards.

Answer (score 0):

On $(0,\infty)$, $f(x)=-x^2$ is concave, $g(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ is convexe, $f(g(x))=-\frac{1}{x^2}$ is concave.